# Block scope and internal linkage?

Tags: c, linkage

From the C18 standard (6.7.9):

> If the declaration of an identifier has **block scope**, and the
> identifier has external or **internal linkage**, the declaration shall
> have no initializer for the identifier.

I have no problem with block scope + external linkage. But, I can't see how can an identifier have block scope and internal linkage. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your global is defined

```
static int hui;
```

it has internal linkage. Then

```
void f(void) {
    extern int hui;

}
```

refers to the same object with internal linkage, even if the keyword says `extern`.

So `extern` is a misnomer and should probably be `linkage` or so.

Comment: I think `extern` still matches its English meaning, as the object is external to the scope of the declaration.

Comment: With this example, there is no immediate reason to redeclare the identifier; it is already visible inside `f`. However, a new declaration does not have to repeat a previous declaration; it can add information to an incomplete type. The first declaration could be `static int (*hui)[];`, while the later declaration can be `extern int (*hui)[3];`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Excellent example. However, where the standard says that in this case types may be compatible (and not e.g. "shall be the same")?